# hydro installing on pandaboard es

Tags: ros, ros-hydro, pandaboard, armhf

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hello
I have installed ros-hydro-ros-base on the platform pandaboard es(the system is ubuntu 12.04 precise) following the instructions of official website. But some common tools packages such as rqt and rviz haven't been installed on the platform. It's difficult to build them from sources to install them on the platform .Because there are many dependencies which i have to install at the same time.
so i want to know weather the ros-base is enough for the platform as a operating environment?
I install a same distro hydro on computer and make computer as a development environment for example I deal with some sensors data and debug some projects on the computer then generate some executed files and I put these executed files on the platform pandaborad to execute them?
Could I do as above?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/219863/hydro-installing-on-pandaboard-es/) by [smcpaddington](https://answers.ros.org/users/24881/smcpaddington/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2015-10-26

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [smcpaddington](https://answers.ros.org/users/24881/smcpaddington/) on 2015-10-26**:
i am confused by this question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes, it is recommended to run things like rqt and rviz offboard from an embedded board like a Panda Board. The small embedded boards do not have much computational power to provide an interactive environment.

ros-base is probably not enough to run your robot, but most of the tools you need are likely available or at least do not need the large set of external dependencies.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2015-10-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0